# Как выделить одну строку целиком в длинном тексте HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется длинный текст внутри одного тэга. Пусть будет DIV. Надо выделить одну строку по событию mouseover.  Т.е. текст, в зависимости от разрешения экрана может переноситься, растягиваться, но при наведении мыши должна выделяться одна строка, как, если бы, это был select
Вот, как на картинке, примерно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Дмитрий, а оно надо?